# ng-repeat with two values from array each repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using bootstrap and would like to ng-repeat through an array but i need to get the 2 values each loop. For the example i wish b.name to be booking[0] and the other b.name to be booking[1]. i am currently adding each row and then adding the value.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="b in booking">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="basicIntake.email_subscription">
            {{b.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="basicIntake.email_subscription">
            {{b.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want even and odd indexes differentation?

Comment: If it is to create a row with 2 col-sm-6 each time it is usesless, just use one row and loop for col-sm-6 as much as you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you can do. You put `ng-if="$even"` so for odd numbers, it won't render it. But, you can render next odd number **in same row** using `{{booking[$index+1].name}}`.

Something like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="b in booking" ng-if="$even">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="basicIntake.email_subscription">
            {{b.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="basicIntake.email_subscription">
            {{booking[$index+1].name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, you can loop through `col-sm-6` instead of its parent.

Comment: Only one who unterstood it was about bootstrap. I like your solution though I would just loop over col-sm-6

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<div class="row" >
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="b in booking | limitTo:2">
        <label><input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="basicIntake.email_subscription">
            {{b.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="b in booking | limitTo:2:2">
        <label><input icheck type="checkbox" ng-model="basicIntake.email_subscription">
            {{b.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```